# ipad - can I write plist to external storage?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am trying to capture data and have that accessible to someone and other computers without networking. There is a camera connection kit that is basically an adapter to connect an SDCard to iPad. Does anyone know if I can use same to write a plist?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you have no direct access to the SD card, and therefore cannot write anything out to it.